# I'm getting an error when grouping the main variant photo

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this error in the VariantPaths section of the code. Can you help me?

My entities are as follows, and I am using Entity Framework 3.1.11 version.

```cs
public class Product : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsVariant { get; set; }
}
public class ProductVariant : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public int AttributeValueId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
}
public class ProductImage : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
    public int ProductAttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
public class ProductStock : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

     public class SelectListProductDto : IDto
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsVariant { get; set; }
        public string PvStockCode { get; set; }  // Pv --> ProductVariant
        public List<string> ProductPaths { get; set; }
        public List<string> VariantPaths { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm attempting to retrieve the first photograph of each main variant. Each product has multiple main variants, and each main variant has multiple photos.

> "Message": "The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: (p.ProductVariantId),
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: ProductImage
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False
> )
> ).FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",

```cs
using (PofuMacrameContext context = new PofuMacrameContext())
{
    var result = (from p in context.Products
                    join pv in context.ProductVariants on p.Id equals pv.ProductId
                    join pi in context.ProductImages on pv.Id equals pi.ProductVariantId
                    join ps in context.ProductStocks on pv.ProductId equals ps.ProductId
                    select new SelectListProductDto
                    {
                        ProductId = p.Id,
                        ProductVariantId = pv.Id,
                        ParentId = pv.ParentId,
                        ProductName = p.ProductName,
                        Description = p.Description,
                        IsVariant = p.IsVariant,
                        PvStockCode = pv.StockCode,
                        Price = ps.Price,
                        ProductPaths = context.ProductImages
                                            .Where(x => x.ProductVariantId == pv.Id)
                                            .Take(2)
                                            .Select(pi => pi.Path)
                                            .ToList(),
                    }).ToList()
        .GroupBy(x => x.ProductVariantId)
        .Select(group => group.First())
        .ToList();


    foreach (var product in result)
    {
        product.VariantPaths = context.ProductImages
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(pi => pi.ProductId == product.ProductId || pi.ProductVariantId != product.ProductVariantId)
            .GroupBy(x => x.ProductVariantId)
            .Select(pi => pi.FirstOrDefault().Path)
            .ToList();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Provide your EF Core version and classes used in this query. With navigation properties there is no need to use explicit joins.

Comment: Edit original question and post these classes with proper formatting. I have not time to reformat this.

Comment: I edited it as you specified.

Comment: Can you show `PofuMacrameContext`?

Answer (score 0):

First part of your query, can be rewritten in this way:

```cs
var productVariants = 
    from p in context.Products
    join pv in context.ProductVariants on p.Id equals pv.ProductId    
    select new 
    {
        p,
        pv
    }

var firstProductVariant = 
    from d in productVariants.Select(d => new { ProductVariantId = d.pv.Id }).Distinct()
    from f in productVariants
        .Where(f => f.pv.Id == d.ProductVariantId)
        .Take(1)
    select f;


var result = (
    from f in firstProductVariant
    join ps in context.ProductStocks on f.pv.ProductId equals ps.ProductId
    select new SelectListProductDto
    {
        ProductId = f.p.Id,
        ProductVariantId = f.pv.Id,
        ParentId = f.pv.ParentId,
        ProductName = f.p.ProductName,
        Description = f.p.Description,
        IsVariant = f.p.IsVariant,
        PvStockCode = f.pv.StockCode,
        Price = ps.Price,
        ProductPaths = context.ProductImages
                            .Where(x => x.ProductVariantId == f.pv.Id)
                            .Take(2)
                            .Select(pi => pi.Path)
                            .ToList(),
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: The VariantPaths field is coming as null. My goal is to get the first photo of each major variant of the product. I can provide the colors as examples of the main variant variants: red, green, blue.

Comment: Yes it is null because it is not initialized in this query. Your second part is doing that, for sure non effective.

Comment: The second section is only retrieving the first photo; however, I want to retrieve the first photo of each main variant and add it to the list.  I'm updating the post and adding the Dto.

Answer (score 0):

The error occur in :

```cs
context.ProductImages
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(...)
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select(pi => pi.FirstOrDefault().Path)
    .ToList();
```

The operand first don't exist in SQL. To simulate this, it's a very tricky query... But min (and max) exist, then you can :

```cs
context.ProductImages
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(...)
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select(pi => pi.Min(pi2 => pi2.Path))
    .ToList();
```

---

PS : Just a warning from the OP code. I see 3 instructions that query in base, two of them in loops... This can cause a lot of interaction with the DB and result in high runtime.

Comment: When I apply this solution, I'm getting the error below:Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. My data is not null

Comment: Is **Nullable reference types** enable? In this case you can try `...Select(...).Where(p => p!= null).ToList();`